# How can I config RTXCommon.jar

Tags: java

I have a java program and I want to use RTXCommon.jar So if I try to use it, I have this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while
loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSe
rial in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
        at com.mcsolution.easyMgmt.panel.utility.panelProgramma.inizializzaLabel
Text(panelProgramma.java:877)
        at com.mcsolution.easyMgmt.panel.utility.panelUtility.creaSwing(panelUti
lity.java:36)
        at com.mcsolution.esp.TestaFrameSalagiochi$MenuLookDemo22$1.actionPerfor
med(TestaFrameSalagiochi.java:118)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Then I have right click on project, java build path, then I have find RTXCommon.jar, select Native Library Path, edit, then I have select the folder C:\SWInstall\dll

In this folder, I have copy rtxSerial.dll rtxParallel.dll. Then I have run the project and works. But if I try to generate jar file then run it, I have the same error.

How can I fixed it?

regards

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things to check that you didn't mention is to verify if you're using a 32bits or 64bits of the RTXCommon.jar, if you are using java 82 Bits you should use RTXCommon.jar 32bits.

Then you have to check if the RTXCommon.jar points to the right location of the native libraries, for that, under eclipse, right click on your project and choose properties then select java build path, in the dialog box click on the little arrow before RTXCommon.jar. Double click on Native library location and enter the path to your DLLs.

If you are willing to run your app on different machines remember to store your DLLs in a common folder (under program files for exemple for windows) that way you can prevent such bug from occurring to other users. Same thing for other operating systems.

Comment: I understand why I'm not able to config this library. I have download from this link http://jlog.org/rxtx-win.html the jar and I have execute the instruction, in eclipse found, but when I tru to generate jar file, I received the some error